# Pattern Matching Assignment in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a problem about assignment via pattern matching in scala. Let's say I have the following:

```
a. Seq.unapplySeq(List(1))

b. val Seq(z) = List(1)

c. val c = List(1) match {
  case Seq(e) => e
}

d. List.unapplySeq(Seq(1))

e. val List(a) = Seq(1)

f. val b = Seq(1) match {
  case List(e) => e
}
```

Only (d) doesn't compile and others compile and run right.

I know that unapplySeq of List is defined in SeqFactory as:

```
abstract class SeqFactory[CC[X] <: Seq[X] with GenericTraversableTemplate[X, CC]] extends GenSeqFactory[CC] with TraversableFactory[CC] {
    applySeq[A](x: CC[A]): Some[CC[A]] = Some(x)
}
```

Because CC is List, Seq in (d) won't type check.

Seems like (a), (b) and (c) are in one group and (d), (e) and (f) are in the other.

In my understanding, destruction of (f) will actually call (d) because what the pattern matching in (f) does is use List to destruct Seq(1).

My question is why (e) and (f) are still right in the case (d) does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a answer for you which doesn't talk about `SeqFactory`:

1. (e) compiles and runs because `Seq(1)` is an shortcut for `Seq.apply(2)` which conveniently always give a `List` instance, ie. here `List(2)`*.  Thus it's assimilable with (b) case.
2. (f) compiles and runs for the same foresaid reason (`Seq(1)` gives a `List(1)` which match `case List(e)`)
3. (d) doesn't compile because what I've said about (e) case in first point is about **instance** and not **type**, ie. `Seq(1)` is an instance of `List` but of type `Seq`.  Here's a demonstration:

   ```
   List.unapplySeq(Seq(1))
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   List.unapplySeq(List(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]])
   ```

   and give:

   ```
   *error: type mismatch;*
   ```

   whereas:

   ```
   List.unapplySeq(List(1))
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
   List.unapplySeq(Seq(1).asInstanceOf[List[Int]])
   ```

   and both give:

   ```
   Some(List(1))
   ```

But, here's the difficulty, you have a point about (f) pattern matching curiosity: It behaves as if scala internally type it as a `List` and not as a `Seq`.

Here's my explanation pattern matching doesn't care about input's type.  It's simple as that (cf. https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#variable-patterns for example).  Here's a demonstration:

```
    var foo: Seq[Int] = List(1)
    foo match { case _: List[Int] => true } // gives true
    foo = 1 to 3
    foo match { case _: List[Int] => true } // throws scala.MatchError
```

Hope it helps.

*To be clearer, if, in another scala implementation, `Vector(2)` would have been given instead by this apply, error would have popped up not during compiling but while running (Alexey Romanov made a good point about this).

Comment: The question is why (e) and (f) _compile_, the compiler doesn't know that "Seq.apply(2) which conveniently always give a List instance".

Comment: Indeed, i use "work" term which is perhaps inexplicit for "compile and run". I'll edit this right away, thank you.

Comment: To show that `Seq(1)` returning a `List` instance doesn't matter for compiling: try `(Vector(1): Seq[Int]) match { case List(e) => e }`. It compiles (and doesn't match at runtime, as expected).

Comment: I agree with you and hope it helps all the more since the question is about compiling among other things.

Comment: I assume you may suggest that my answer needed clarifications. Also, I took liberty to add a footnote and refer to you in it. Hope I've been judicious, otherwise, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

(e) is translated to (f), correct. But if you look at https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-sequences, the only requirement for `unapplySeq` is on result type, not argument type. So my guess (the specification doesn't actually specify this and I can't check at the moment) is that (f) tests that it's argument is a `List` before calling `unapplySeq`, i.e. it's internally something like

```
Seq(1) match {
    case canUnapplySeq: List[Int] => 
        ... List.unapplySeq(canUnapplySeq) // (d) only invoked here
}
```

Note that the argument applies to `unapply` as well.